# I am trying to append an arithmetic operation list into another empty list and returning the list

Tags: python

I want to append an arithmetic operation string into another list by splitting every numbers and operators. when i append 3.1 it becomes 3.0 then 1.0 instead.

I added float

```
def tokenization(expr):
    opr = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^","(",")"]
    tokens = []
    for char in expr:       
        if char.isdigit():                  
            tokens.append(float(char)
        if char == '':
            continue
        if char in opr:
            tokens.append(char)
    return tokens
```

Comment: Since you are reading in a single character at a time there is no way for your code to know if its a float or not. You need to add a condition that if you see a period, check the tokens before/after

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
def tokenization(expr):
    opr = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "(", ")"]
    tokens = []
    digit_readed, dot_readed, zero_readed = 0, 0, 0
    for idx, char in enumerate(expr):
        if char == " ":
            digit_readed, dot_readed, zero_readed = 0, 0, 0
        elif char in opr:
            tokens.append(char)
            digit_readed, dot_readed, zero_readed = 0, 0, 0
        else:
            if char.isdigit():
                digit_readed += 1
                if char == "0":
                    zero_readed += 1
                    if dot_readed > 0:
                        continue
            elif char == "." and digit_readed > 0:
                dot_readed += 1
                zero_readed, digit_readed = 0, 0
                continue
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unexpected '{}' on {} symbol".format(char, idx + 1))

            if dot_readed == 1:
                tmp = (str(round(tokens[-1])) + "." if digit_readed == zero_readed + 1 else str(tokens[-1])) + \
                       "0" * zero_readed
                tokens[-1] = float(tmp + char)
                zero_readed = 0
            elif digit_readed == 1:
                tokens.append(float(char))
            elif digit_readed > 1:
                tokens[-1] = float(str(round(tokens[-1])) + char)

    return tokens

print(tokenization("(3.1 + 6*2^2) * (2 - 1)"))
```

**Result:**

```
['(', 3.1, '+', 6.0, '*', 2.0, '^', 2.0, ')', '*', '(', 2.0, '-', 1.0, ')']
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation. Also the code fails for the case `print(tokenization("(3.301 + 6*2^2) * (2 - 1)"))`

Comment: @BenT, thanks for noticing that, I've forgot about zero :D Edited code, now there's no such as problem.

Comment: but the numbers has to be floating point as it all has to be 2.0 and so on

Comment: @barathan, I've edited code. Now it should fit your requirements. It's not an easy script, so feel free to ask anything regarding codes.

Comment: @OlvinRoght . is it possible if i want to create another function to evaluate the output of the function tokenization without using any built function such as eval() ?

Comment: @barathan, everything is possible :) Take a look on [reverse polish notation](https://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/2116-reverse-polish-notation-rpn.html).

Comment: i tried using that method but somehow i am having truble when it come to the "**" operator .

Comment: @barathan, code I've provided produces this output, what's wrong?

Comment: @OlvinRoght hey is it okay if you provide some comments for the code above, it will be easier for me to understand

Comment: @barathan, it'd take some time to comment each line. I recommend you to launch script in debug mode and trace over each instruction. If you'll have any question after this, you can ask me.